# Class static members contributing to program memory footprint even if class is not used

Tags: c++, arrays, static

In class I want to have constant array of constant C strings:

.cpp

```
const char* const  Colors::Names[] = {
    "red",
    "green"
    };
```

.h

```
class Colors {
public:
    static const char* const  Names[];
};
```

The array should be common to all instances of class Colors (even though I plan to have just one instance but it should not metter), hence declaring array static.

The requirment is that if class is not instantied, array should not consume any memory in binary file.
However, with above solution, it does consume:

```
 .rodata._ZN6Colors5NamesE
                0x00000000        0x8
```

not sure about C strings itself as cannot find them in a map file but I assume they consume memory as well.

I know that one solution to this would be to use constexpr and C++17 where is it no longer needed to have definition of static constexpr members outside of class.
However, for some reasons (i.e. higher compilation times in my build system and slighlty higher program memory footprint) I don't want to change c++ standard version.

Another idea is to drop static (as I plan to have one instance anyway). However, the first issue with this solution is that I have to specify array size, which I would rather prefer not to do, otherwise I get:

```
error: flexible array member 'Colors::Names' in an otherwise empty 'class Colors'
```

Second issue is that array is placed in RAM section (inside class object), and only C strings are placed in FLASH memory.

Does anyone know other solutuions to this issue?

PS. My platform is Stm32 MCU and using GCC ARM compiler

EDIT (to address some of the answers in comments)
As suggested in comments this can't be done with just static members.
So the question should probably actually be: **How to create (non-static) class array member, that's placed in read only memory (not initialized), which is placed in a memory only if the class is actually used in the program  and preferably common for all instances of that class? Array itself is only used from that class.**

Some background info:
Let's say that array has size of 256, and each C string 40 chars. That's 1kB for array + 10kB for C strings (32 bit architecture). Class is a part of library that is used by different projects (programs). If the class is not used in that project then I don't want that it (and it's array) would occupy even a single byte beacuse I need that FLASH space for other things, therefore compresion is not an option.

If there will be no other solutions then I will consider possiblity of removing unused sections by linker (alothough was hoping for a simpler solution).
Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're surprised that the array takes up space inside the binary file, not in memory once loaded?

Comment: As for a possible reason the array uses space in the file might be that the compiler already knows the contents of it, because the location of the strings is known at compile-time.

Comment: _The requirment is that if class is not instantied, array should not consume any memory in binary file._ I doubt that this is achievable. The alternative would be to have a `static vector` which is populated on demand (like a singleton). It will reduce the memory foot print as long as it isn't used but increase that memory foot print when it's used (with the administrative data of `vector` which is additional to a plain array though these are not that big) plus the size of code and data to initialize it on demand.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Basically, I don't want to have objects that are not used in a program to occupy FLASH memory. I assume that if it is visible in a map file then it also contributes to binary file size and as a result consumes FLASH memory.

Comment: Static class members exist regardless of whether any class objects are ever created. No real surprise here.

Comment: What you want is really impossible. You can make it take up *less* space by using pointers and dynamic allocation (for example) and do run-time initialization, but then the pointer variable itself would still need space. It would also impact run-time at boot for the initialization. You have a trade-off: Either use more space but less run-time, or use less space and more run-time. You simply can't have no-space and no run-time.

Comment: "I don't want to have objects that are not used in a program to occupy FLASH memory." You need a linker that can perform garbage collection on objects and remove unreferenced data. GNU ld can do this with the -gc-sections flag, but you need to place each variable you want to collect this way in its own section.

Comment: You could also consider to compress the constant data and uncompressing it in initialization on first access. But again, that has to be a lot of data to compensate the size of additional code needed for this (not to mention the additional run-time which will be consumed and may or may not be an issue).

Comment: If the color names consists of lower case letters only, the characters might be stored with 5 bit integers. In this case, uncompressing could be quite simple, consisting of a few bit mask and shift operations... ;-)

Comment: Another point of clarification (that I really think you need to add to the question itself): Is the array actually *used* in your program? If not then you should read the documentation about the linker and its possibilities to removed unused sections (as mentioned by @n.m.). If it *is* used in your program, then you can't remove it.